# Syntax error ... Jython/Python

Tags: syntax, syntax-error, jython

Hi I'm doing my first programming assignment (it's with Jython, i.e. Python using Java) and I've run into a syntax error on line 14 (bolded below). I've tried changing the variable to something less useful like "L" or "I" but it still gives the error. It's annoying because it makes no sense. I have tried indenting again and adding comments around it.

This is a program that outputs a picture of a soccer ball factory. It's as much as an artistic project as a comp sci project. So the printing looks complicated but is only like long checklist for building.

```
def prettyPic():
  #building materials and parts
  spacer = " "
  ceiling_part = "-"
  ball = "o"
  wheel = ""
  door_joint = "@"
  left_half_arch = "/"
  right_half_arch = "\\"
  ladder = "\\"
  wall = "|"
  glass = (
  #biox
  **left_box = "u"
  right_box = "u"**
  #begin printing
   print (spacer*30 + ceiling_part*30)
   print (spacer*32 + wall*1) + (spacer*47 + wall*1)
   #three balls, leaving space for drop
   print (spacer*32 + wall*1) + (ball*27) + (wall*1)
   #arches, not touching ceiling
  etc, etc
```

Comment: Syntax error: `glass = (`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
glass = (
```

This means that to `glass` variable, you assign tuple just like:

```
glass = (1, 2, 'some string')
```

Python interpreter searches for termination of just opened tuple but it finds only Python code that is not correct in this context.

Remove or comment out line with `glass`, or assign to `glass` variable some value.